# OpenCV 3: Why does the UI render incorrectly?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0, spyder

I am a new to openCV and trying its examples from documentation. I am doing the trackbar as the color palette [example](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dc8/tutorial_py_trackbar.html).

But my UI renders in wrong order as well as crops the switch title: OFF.

[image]

where it is supposed to be like this.

[image]

I am using macbook pro with macOS 10.13.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV's Highgui module uses QT as a backend. QT renders elements differently depending on the OS that is using it. I believe that this is because QT uses UI elements that are native to the OS. So a frame in Windows will look like a Windows Frame, a frame in Linux will look like a Linux frame.

This is what the same example produces in Windows:

[image: Windows GUI example]

You can get the slider bars to fit the window by changing:

```
cv2.namedWindow('image')
```

to:

```
cv2.namedWindow('image',cv2.WND_PROP_AUTOSIZE)
```

Doing that produces this output (in Windows):

[image: Windows example with autosize property]

Comment: May be thats the case anyways I have opened an issue in openCV repo.